# Nested modules in library not showing source

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jitpack

I’m working on an Android Library for all the common pieces of code we reuse in a lot of projects.
In the Library I have a nested file structure so I can order the sub modules more clearly.
The project can be found on Github to make it more clear how the structure is (https://github.com/appwise-labs/AndroidCore)

```
--| Core (library)
--| data
  --| Networking (library)
  --| Room (library)
--| customViews
  --| CustomView1 (library)
```

Everything compiles correctly and I can also add the dependencies to a project.
But only the sourceCode of the Core module is visible when I want to inspect the code of the dependencies. I can also verify that the Jitpack build log states that a `sources.jar` file for the Core module has been created.

In case I add a new module to the root of the repo, the source of that new module is visible.

I'm wondering what it exactly is that I'm missing. Is it something specific in the Gradle configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding an extra task and part to the `afterEvaluate`

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "sources"
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release

                groupId = 'com.github.appwise-labs'

                artifact(sourceJar) // this thing!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This made sure that the sources.jar was created for the submodule and added when the dependency got used in a project